# Why do I get segmentation fault if I don't use "new" keyword?

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

The following code generates segmentation fault. I don't get segmentation fault if I allocate memory on heap for my node1. (`Node* node1 = new Node`). My question is why do I get segmentation fault now? Shouldn't `Node* node1;` line get memory for my node1 on the stack?

```
class Node{
    public:
        int data;
        Node* next;
};

int main(){
    Node* node1;
    node1->data = 5;

    cout << node1->data << endl;
}
```

I printed the address of node1 adding a cout line:

```
int main(){
    Node* node1;
    cout << &node1 << endl;
    node1->data = 5;

    cout << node1->data << endl;
}
```

Now the error is gone. Whenever I comment the cout line the error comes back. Can anyone explain that behaviour?

Comment: `node1` is uninitialized

Comment: To elaborate, `Node*` is the address in memory of a `Node`. If you don't initialize it, it's going to point to any old address. So when you try and access a node there, the OS throws up its arms and issues a segfault because you're trying to access a segment of memory you don't have permission to access.

Comment: @parktomatomi I edited the question. So trying to reach the address of the pointer gives me the permission, Is that right? Is that the reason the error disappears?

Comment: ***Can anyone explain that behaviour?*** This is what undefined behavior is. Anything can happen when you violate the rules of the language.

Comment: @NoN Only the OS can arbitrarily access addresses in memory. Your program is running in what's called userland, so you have to ask the OS for a block of memory you can access. That's what `new` does under the hood.

Answer (score 3):

> Shouldn't `Node* node1;` line get memory for my `node1` on the stack?

`Node* node1;` gets memory on the stack for the pointer `node1`. However, after that, the pointer `node1` is uninitialized and isn't pointing anywhere valid. That's why you need to make it point somewhere valid before changing the data where it points to, and one way of doing that is with `new`.

Comment: Note if you were to not use a pointer, and just initialize `Node node1`, you wouldn't need to use `new`, but that's not (usually) what you want.

Comment: I edited the question. Why the segmentation fault disappears when I try to reach the address of the node1?

Comment: @NoN You shouldn't edit questions into different ones. Anyway, what you're doing is undefined behavior, and there's no guarantee whatsoever with UB. It can seem to work sometimes and crash your program at other times, or do something entirely different. Therefore there is no gain in trying to figure out why UB does what it does.

Comment: Stop suggesting `new` friend, please.

Comment: I expect this academic exercise requires the use of `new`.

Answer (score 2):

> Question:  why do I get segmentation fault now?

Answer: Whenever we access memory, which is out from program segment, we get segmentation fault.

> Question: Shouldn't Node* node1; line get memory for my node1 on the
>   stack?

Answer: 
1. In `Node * node1;` node1 is just pointer type variable which will be pointing to Node object. node1 pointer size does not depend on member of Node structure. Its just 4 byte long in 32 bit OS/platform. This pointer variable should be used to store address only
of pointer type here its `Node`.

2. Currently its holding garbage value.
3. We have to create object (allocate memory) of type Node either using `"Node *node1 = new Node;`" or locally (not dynamic)  as "`Node node1;` and Now we can access memory created for Node either using -> (pointer to member) operator or using . (dot) operator.

> Question: I printed the address of node1 adding a cout line?

Answer: you are printing address of pointer variable not Node object.

> Question: Whenever I comment the cout line the error comes back. Can
>   anyone explain that behavior?

Answer: 1. Behavior will be unpredictable, because you are working with garbage address(present in node1 pointer variable).

2. if pointer variable (garbage) is pointing to memory which is protected/used by other process then we will get segmentation fault.
3. if garbage address pointing to memory which is not yet used/protected by other process, we may not get any error.

I hope its clear now. please let me know if any followup question.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use your object, a constructor must exist and be used when you instantiate your object. The constructor can be defined implicitly by the compiler under some conditions if you do not provide any, but eventually, the constructor must be there if you want an object to be instantiated.